# Can't display the style

Tags: java, geotools, sld

When I load the feature source and style in the map layer it does not always display.

The feature and style were loaded in mapcontent:
(http://tva1.sinaimg.cn/large/007X8olVly1g6s6dbbhqdj30w00i0ta5.jpg
)

features[image: features]：
(http://tva1.sinaimg.cn/large/007X8olVly1g6s6ejjsnwj30wz0kgab0.jpg
)

features in database：

```
WIDTH_LEFT  LINE_STYLE                       WKT
N   NormalRoute LINESTRING(82.3308944444444 44.89158888888889,82.89986111111108 44.59994444444439)
N   NormalRoute LINESTRING(82.3308944444444 44.89158888888889,81.32899999999999 43.9581388888889)
N   NormalRoute LINESTRING(120.1201694444439 47.363625,120.4744444444439 47.7275)
N   NormalRoute LINESTRING(120.1201694444439 47.363625,120.706388888889 47.1844444444444)
N   NormalRoute LINESTRING(89.12944444444439 43.03111111111109,89.39305555555559 43.55777777777779)
N   NormalRoute LINESTRING(89.39305555555559 43.55777777777779,89.5169444444444 43.8041666666667)
N   NormalRoute LINESTRING(89.5169444444444 43.8041666666667,89.60913888888891 43.98631944444439)
N   NormalRoute LINESTRING(120.2911666666669 35.97711111111109,120.248611111111 36.2975)
N   NormalRoute LINESTRING(120.248611111111 36.2975,120.3788888888889 36.5316666666667)
N   NormalRoute LINESTRING(120.0086111111109 37.13499999999999,120.445555555556 36.98333333333329)
N   NormalRoute LINESTRING(120.3683972222219 36.2873138888889,120.4955555555559 36.38)
N   NormalRoute LINESTRING(120.4805555555559 36.1166666666667,120.2911666666669 35.97711111111109)
N   NormalRoute LINESTRING(102.324019444444 38.55711111111109,103.3783333333329 38.41166666666669)
Y   NormalRoute LINESTRING(112.955 17.85833333333329,112.283333333333 17)
Y   NormalRoute LINESTRING(112.283333333333 17,111.05 15.3583333333333)
Y   NormalRoute LINESTRING(100.9649999999999 22.7183333333333,100.555833333333 24.12194444444439)
Y   NormalRoute LINESTRING(100.555833333333 24.12194444444439,100.283333333333 25.045)
Y   NormalRoute LINESTRING(100.283333333333 25.045,100.255833333333 25.13833333333329)
Y   NormalRoute LINESTRING(100.255833333333 25.13833333333329,100 26)
Y   NormalRoute LINESTRING(100 26,100 27.94888888888889)
Y   NormalRoute LINESTRING(100 27.94888888888889,100 30.28055555555559)
Y   NormalRoute LINESTRING(100 30.28055555555559,100 30.92888888888889)
Y   NormalRoute LINESTRING(100 30.92888888888889,100 32)
Y   NormalRoute LINESTRING(100 32,99 32.6016666666667)
Y   NormalRoute LINESTRING(99 32.6016666666667,97.71833333333329 33.37666666666669)
Y   NormalRoute LINESTRING(97.71833333333329 33.37666666666669,96.5 34.1083333333333)
Y   NormalRoute LINESTRING(96.5 34.1083333333333,94.20305555555559 35.45083333333329)
```

feature Type:

```
SimpleFeatureType createFeatureType(String typeName, Class type) {
    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    builder.setName(typeName);
    builder.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
    builder.add("the_geom", type);
    builder.add("CODE_ID",String.class);
    builder.add("WIDTH_LEFT",String.class);
    builder.add("LINE_STYLE",String.class);


    final SimpleFeatureType TYPE = builder.buildFeatureType();
    return TYPE;
}
```

the whole .sld file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<sld:UserStyle xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
  <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
    <sld:Rule>
      <sld:Name>WidthWay</sld:Name>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>WIDTH_LEFT</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>Y</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>1000000.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
      <sld:LineSymbolizer>
        <sld:Stroke>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#A8A8A8</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.5</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">12</sld:CssParameter>
        </sld:Stroke>
      </sld:LineSymbolizer>
    </sld:Rule>
    <sld:Rule>
      <sld:Name>NomalWay</sld:Name>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>LINE_STYLE</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>NormalRoute</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>1000000.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
      <sld:LineSymbolizer>
        <sld:Stroke>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#001b55</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.6</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</sld:CssParameter>
        </sld:Stroke>
      </sld:LineSymbolizer>
    </sld:Rule>
    <sld:Rule>
      <sld:Name>FansWay</sld:Name>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>LINE_STYLE</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>FansRoute</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>1000000.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
      <sld:LineSymbolizer>
        <sld:Stroke>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#001b55</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.6</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">15.0 8.0</sld:CssParameter>
        </sld:Stroke>
      </sld:LineSymbolizer>
    </sld:Rule>
    <sld:Rule>
      <sld:Name>VisualFlightWay</sld:Name>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>LINE_STYLE</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>VisualFlightRoute</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>1000000.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
      <sld:LineSymbolizer>
        <sld:Stroke>
          <sld:GraphicStroke>
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:Mark>
                <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
                <sld:Fill>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#001b55</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Fill>
                <sld:Stroke>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#001b55</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.6</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Stroke>
              </sld:Mark>
              <sld:Size>2</sld:Size>
            </sld:Graphic>
          </sld:GraphicStroke>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#001b55</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.6</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">2.0 8.0</sld:CssParameter>
        </sld:Stroke>
      </sld:LineSymbolizer>
    </sld:Rule>
  </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
</sld:UserStyle>
```

Comment: please ! if any trouble in my problem,just point out...

Comment: We need to see the content of some of your features and the whole of the SLD, the other code is irrelevant - though you should probably use a DataStore not an SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same confusion that you have loaded the style and featuresource in the map layer,but it not display,maybe you should adjustment the **MaxScaleDenominator** or **MinScaleDenominator** in .sld file. It's a amusing question,but it cost my 1 week and 6 reputations.